# Boostrap 4 modal is not working in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I am trying to add modal popup of bootstrap 4 within my ASP.NET page. Note when I tried to popup the modal it makes nothing but a postback only. I saw some suggestions on the net saying add code for modal outside form tag, update panel etc but nothing works for me. I checked the same code in a plain html page and it's working perfectly there. Note that I have an update panel within my page. I tried adding code both inside and outside of this update panel. I don't know what's wrong with it?? Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code.

```
 <button id="btnModal" class="btn btn-info" >Show Modal</button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="BootstrapModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h6 class="modal-title">warning!</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Select row(s) to delete.
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnModal').click(function () {
                $("#BootstrapModal").modal("show");
            });
        });
```

Jquery and everything are there and works fine. But this modal calling gives me a postback only....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these to your button

```
<button type="button" id="btnModal" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#BootstrapModal" >Show Modal</button>
```

and remove your `document.ready` function.

Comment: is there any way to call this modal with using a script function? because I want to fire this modal when no rows are selected in a gridview.

Comment: manually you could call modal with `$('#myModal').modal('toggle');
$('#myModal').modal('show');
$('#myModal').modal('hide');`